# Trying to group numbers in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to group a number from E column starting with 1, the result should be like as below:

```
Column
E   I
1   1-52
.   54-56
.   58-59
.
52
54
55
56
58
59
```

And I start to write like this:

```
Sub Group_Numbers()
  Dim a As Variant, b As Variant
  Dim i As Long, k As Long
  
Range("I1") = Range("E1")
k = 1
  a = Range("E1", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
  ReDim b(1 To UBound(a), 1 To 1)
  For i = 2 To UBound(a)
  If a(i, 1) <> Val(a(i - 1, 1)) + 1 Then
    k = k + 1
    b(k, 1) = a(i, 1)
    Else
        b(k, 1) = Split(b(k, 1), "-")(0) & -a(i, 1)
    End If
  Next i
    Range("I2").Resize(l).Value = b
End Sub
```

However, it prompts an error 9 subscript out of range. Hope to get help right here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: Line 15 : b(k, 1) = Split(b(k, 1), "-")(0) & -a(i, 1)

Comment: Should that be ` Split(b(k, 1), "-")(0) & "-" & a(i, 1) `

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim ws As Worksheet  ' define worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim Data() As Variant  ' read input data into array
    Data = ws.Range("E1", "E" & LastRow).Value2
    
    Dim OutData() As Variant  ' define output array
    ReDim OutData(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To 1) As Variant
    Dim iOut As Long
    iOut = 1
    
    Dim StartVal As Long
    StartVal = Data(1, 1)  ' initialize start value of a group
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To UBound(Data, 1) ' loop through values
        ' check if value is previous value +1
        If Data(iRow, 1) <> Data(iRow - 1, 1) + 1 Then
            ' if not write output from StartVal to previos value
            OutData(iOut, 1) = StartVal & "-" & Data(iRow - 1, 1)
            iOut = iOut + 1
            ' and set curent value as new group start
            StartVal = Data(iRow, 1)
        End If
    Next iRow
    
    ' close last group
    OutData(iOut, 1) = StartVal & "-" & Data(iRow - 1, 1)
    
    ' write array back to cells
    ws.Range("I1").Resize(RowSize:=iOut).NumberFormat = "@"  'format cells as text so `1-2` does not get converted into date.
    ws.Range("I1").Resize(RowSize:=iOut).Value2 = OutData
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: Straight forward solution using arrays +:) .. Fyi Instead of row-wise loops my approach evaluates Excel's formula `FILTER()` upon the entire range block to get end range numbers as base for the resulting strings. @PEH

Comment: Thank you PEH and T.M. for your analysis. :) Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative via Excel's `Filter()` function *(vers. MS 365)***

Disposing of the new dynamic array features you can profit from a worksheet-related *formula evaluation* via a tabular filter upon the data range rows compared with the same range shifted by 1 resulting in an array of `endRows` numbers. This is the base for a `results` array which joins start and end values.

The following code allows to define a flexible source range, as the evaluation takes care of the actual start row in the indicated data column.

**Example call** *//edited responding to comment*

```
Sub Grouping()
'0) get data
    Dim src  As Range
    Set src = Sheet1.Range("E1:E59")        ' change to your needs
    Dim data As Variant
    If src.Rows.Count > 1 Then              ' is the usual case
        data = src.Value2                   '     get 2-dim datafield array
    Else                                    ' a one liner is the exception
        ReDim data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)          '     create 2-dim by ReDim
        data(1, 1) = Application.Index(src, 1, 1)
    End If
'1a)prepare formula evaluation of endRows
    Dim EndPattern As String
    EndPattern = "=LET(data,$,FILTER(ROW(OFFSET(data,1,0))-" & src.Row & ",ABS(OFFSET(data,1,0)-data)>1))"
    EndPattern = Replace(EndPattern, "$", src.Address(False, False))
'1b)evaluate formula
    Dim endRows: endRows = src.Parent.Evaluate(EndPattern)
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'2) get results
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Dim results: results = getResults(data, endRows)    '<< Help function getResults
'3) write to any target
    With Sheet1.Range("I1")
        .Resize(UBound(results), 1) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

**Help function `getResults()`** *//added responding to comment*

The usual result of an evaluation is a 1-based 2-dim array with two exceptions code has to provide for:

- a) non-findings (which would result only in a returned error value),
- b) only a single return value (which is a 1-dim array).

Not enough with these exceptions, the tricky comparison of identical `endRows` blocks - being shifted by 1 row - makes it necessary to check for the actual last row number if not comprised in `endRows`. - *Imo this might have been the commented issue by @TecLao.*

```
Function getResults(ByRef data, ByRef endRows)
'Purpose: combine value ranges
    Dim results As Variant
    Dim n As Long: n = UBound(data)
'a) no end row returned by shift-formula evaluation
    If IsError(endRows) Then ReDim endRows(1 To 1): endRows(1) = n
'b) one end row found
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(endRows) = 1 Then
        ReDim results(1 To IIf(endRows(1) < n, 2, 1), 1 To 1)
        'write results
        results(1, 1) = "'" & data(1, 1) & "-" & data(endRows(1), 1)
        If UBound(results) = 2 Then
            results(2, 1) = _
                "'" & data(endRows(1) + 1, 1) & _
                "-" & _
                data(n, 1)
        End If
'c) several end rows found
    Else
        Dim increment As Long
        If endRows(UBound(endRows), 1) < n Then increment = 1
        'write results
        ReDim results(1 To UBound(endRows) + increment, 1 To 1)
        results(1, 1) = "'" & data(1, 1) & "-" & data(endRows(1, 1), 1)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To UBound(endRows)
            results(i, 1) = _
                          "'" & _
                          data(endRows(i - 1, 1) + 1, 1) & _
                          "-" & _
                          data(endRows(i, 1), 1)
        Next
        If increment Then
            results(i, 1) = "'" & data(endRows(i - 1, 1) + 1, 1) & "-" & data(n, 1)
        End If
        
    End If
    'function return
    getResults = results
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @T.M. for your share. I tried but on ln 13 Dim results: `code ReDim results(1 To UBound(endRows), 1 To 1)` shows type mismatch...

Comment: @TecLao I get no issues. - Did you **change** any part in code? How did you define your `src` data range (column E)? - if not via the procject's Code(Name) you have to fully qualify it. - Tip: You can insert `Stop` in code, step forward via {F8} clicks and control results in the VB Editor's local window. So you can check *where* you don't get wanted results (e.g. if the evaluation leads to an error value)

Comment: @TecLao Thx for feedback, will revise code for the special cases of non-findings or only one single end row as this would not result in a 2-dim array

Comment: @TecLao Have added a help function to the main code which should **solve all possible issues** (non-findings, only one row vs. several rows because different dimensions and/or vartypes ..). Would appreciate feed back.